# MySQL CREATE PROCEDURE syntax error

Tags: mysql

I've tried every possible combination I can think of to resolve this error but it keeps happening. Any help appreciated. This is just modifying the `sakila` sample database to do more complex things with.

See towards bottom I labeled the error with `-- HERE!`.

```
USE sakila;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_randCustMult;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_randCustMult()

BEGIN
/* section of code left out for troubleshooting
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = customer AND column_name = multiplier) 
        THEN ALTER TABLE customer DROP COLUMN multiplier;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = customer AND column_name = cust_ranking) 
        THEN ALTER TABLE customer DROP COLUMN cust_ranking;

 END IF;
*/
-- add new columns
ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD COLUMN multiplier DECIMAL(3,2) AFTER active;
/* this column not relevant now
ALTER TABLE customer
    ADD COLUMN cust_ranking VARCHAR(10) AFTER multiplier;
*/
    -- declare a counter
    SET @start = (SELECT MIN(customer_id) FROM customer);
    SET @stop  = (SELECT MAX(customer_id) FROM customer);
    -- start while loop
    WHILE @start <= @stop 
            DO
            UPDATE customer
            -- insert multiplier based on random distribution
            SET multiplier =
            (SELECT 
                (CASE 
                    WHEN RAND() <= 0.65 THEN 1.00
                    WHEN RAND() <= 0.90 THEN 0.85
                    WHEN RAND() <= 1.00 THEN 1.05
                END)
            )
            WHERE customer_id = @start;
            -- tick counter one up
            SET @start = @start + 1;
    END WHILE;
-- HERE! syntax error on END before //
END//
DROP PROCEDURE sp_randCustMult//
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT1**: To clarify, MySql version is:

`MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Mac OS X version 6.1.4  revision 11773 build 1454`

And the error response from Workbench:

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 35`

**EDIT2**: Edited code as suggested. Error no longer happens, however data is not being updated at all. (all `NULL` in new column)

Comment: It seems the problem is elsewhere, I think with `RAND()` I will post an answer once I figure it out. Thanks all.

Comment: Why are you looping? Why not just do `UPDATE customer SET multiplier = CASE … END` without any `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CREATE PROCEDURE` doesn't match the required syntax [as described in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html) (simplified below by including just the relevant parts):

> > `CREATE`
> >         `PROCEDURE` *sp_name* ([*proc_parameter*[,...]])
> >         *routine_body*
> >
> > *routine_body*:
> >         *Valid SQL routine statement*
>
> The *routine_body* consists of a valid SQL routine statement. This can be a simple statement such as [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) or [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), or a compound statement written using `BEGIN` and `END`. Compound statements can contain declarations, loops, and other control structure statements. The syntax for these statements is described in [Section 13.6, “MySQL Compound-Statement Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html).

Therefore, this junk…

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = customer AND column_name = multiplier) 
    THEN ALTER TABLE customer DROP COLUMN multiplier;
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = customer AND column_name = cust_ranking) 
    THEN ALTER TABLE customer DROP COLUMN cust_ranking;
END IF;
```

… is illegal.  Perhaps you meant to move it into the `BEGIN … END` compound statement?

---

You also need a semicolon after [`END WHILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html).

Comment: Error still happens after moving `IF EXISTS` statements into the `BEGIN ... END` statement...

Comment: It also happens if I comment out the whole `IF EXISTS` statement, evidently the problem must be elsewhere :(

Answer (score 0):

All functional logic must be between the tags BEGIN and END

So the IF conditions and alter query stuff must lie between BEGIN and END tags of procedure..

Thanks

Comment: Modified code, no longer getting an error but the script does nothing. See edits to OP, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issues, here is the solution on CR:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51603/mysql-modifying-sakila-database